# How can I interpret the model created by the algorithm C5.0 for decision tree in R?

Tags: r, classification, cart

I have this simple dataframe with some `NA`s.

```
features<-data.frame(M1=c(1,1,0),M2=c(1,1,0),M3=c(0,0,1),C1=c("white","green",NA),
                     C2=c("violet","cyan",NA),C3=c(NA,NA,"red"))
print(features)

   M1 M2 M3    C1     C2   C3
 1  1  1  0 white violet <NA>
 2  1  1  0 green   cyan <NA>
 3  0  0  1  <NA>   <NA>  red
```

Each rows is a distinct class:

```
target<-as.factor(c("A","B","C"))
```

I try to train a tree with C5.0 algorithm:

```
model<-C50::C5.0(features,target)
```

but I get this output:

```
c50 code called exit with value 1

print(model)

Call:
C5.0.default(x = features, y = target)

Classification Tree
Number of samples: 3 
Number of predictors: 6 

Tree size: 0 

Non-standard options: attempt to group attributes
```

If I try to predict, I will get an error:

```
C50::predict.C5.0(model,features[1,])

Error in C50::predict.C5.0(model, features[1, ]) : 
  either a tree or rules must be provided
```

What am I missing?

It seems to me that I can classify my items for example just looking at `M3` and `C1`:

```
if ( M3==1 ){
   class is C
} else {
   if ( C1==white ) {
      class is A
   } else {
      class is B
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The model that you are proposing would have three leaves,  each with one instance.  It generally leads to overfitting if you create nodes in your decision tree that represent very small numbers of instances,  so the defaults for C5.0 require that each leaf must have at least two instances.   (Even that is very aggressive.)  That default is a little bit buried in the documentation. If you look at the documentation for C5.0 by using `?C5.0` you will see that there is an argument `C5.0Control` and a link to get help on that.  Going to the help on `C5.0Control` you will see the default setting `minCases = 2`.  So with your tiny example,  C5.0 is not willing to create any nodes below the root , at least not with the default setting on minCases.

Comment: Thank you! Tested with `minCases = 1` but got the same result...